# Add a 'Total' column to a CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file including a header row like this:

```
col_0, col_1, col_2
row_1, 10, 20
row_2, 30, 40
```

and I want to generate a new CSV looking like this:

```
col_0, col_1, col_2, total
row_1, 10, 20, 30
row_2, 30, 40, 70
```

I've used CSV.read and CSV.open, which work as expected (I can write out the total as a new column in the rows) but haven't found a way to treat the header differently, so that the word 'total' is added. The source file comes very plain, with no quote marks as text delimiters, I want the output to be the same.

Comment: so you want to generate new file or append header to existing **csv** file ?

Comment: @VishalTajPM My goal is to write out a new file. The original source file has a header line, the new file should have the same header line as the original, but with one extra column label appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open a CSV file to write, you can firstly push the headers, and then iterate over the values you want as rows.

```
CSV.open('file.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << %w[col_0 col_1 col_2 total]
  array_of_arrays.each { |row| csv << row }
end
```

First you open the file in write mode, then push the headers, and then over an array of arrays containing each value for each row, you push each of them.